# core-list doesn't display all my items in scroll view?

Tags: polymer

What am I doing wrong?

http://embed.plnkr.co/9sxQHUcsBImmPTIZ3Fgq/preview

Why does it not fill my page?

What did I miss in the documentation?

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-list.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://youtu.be/2UKPRbrw3Kk?t=2m37s

Should have set explicit height to 10 or something small